# Spring-boot 2.2.x increased CPU

Tags: spring-boot, cpu-usage

We have a Spring-boot REST application running on 3 production machines. A recent update from Spring-boot 2.1.8 to 2.2.2 has shown an initial increase of CPU by at least double. This load then increases over time whereas the old version stays steady.

I have managed to narrow this down to 2.2.x as building with 2.1.11 is ok, but 2.2.0 shows the problem.

To give an idea of scale, the old version stays at around 6% regardless of load, whereas the new version starts at around 15% and gradually increases to over 100% after about 10 hours.

I can see the initial rise with an identical build, only changing the Spring-boot version. The application uses spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-actuator.

Any ideas? Should I raise this over at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues ?

Comment: Have you tried the latest 2.2.x build (2.2.4 at the moment)?

Comment: Could you please share us your dependencies that you have? looks like one of them has `a performance issue`.

Comment: 2.2.2 and 2.2.4 exhibit the same issue

Comment: with regard to dependencies. the only two that change are spring-boot-web and actuator versions. Of course, they in turn drag in load of other dependencies that are of course updated.

Comment: I've also seen a similar issue. Trying to get info where the CPU time is being spent but we don't have that yet. Would you please be able to raise it over at spring boot issues so it gets a wider audience?

Comment: Apologies @BenRowland, I've only just seen your comment. I've been trying to reproduce the issue in our test/lab environment - without success. Looking at the comment below it seems we might have a way forward. We are planning a limited live test to try and resolve by upgrading. I will update when I have an outcome.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21750

Comment: We update one of our servers to use 2.3.0 and it does indeed look stable after 72 hours. Good news I think

Answer (score 2):

This is very likely to be linked to a bug in Spring Framework that was fixed in Spring Framework 5.2.6 (or Spring Boot 2.2.7). There was a memory leak in case of concurrent requests/responses with the same media type.

See [the dedicated issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24886) as well as a report sent by a developer with [lots of details](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25043). Note that this happens with both MVC and WebFlux.

Answer (score 1):

We've seen this issue in some of our services, but upgrading to 2.2.7 looks to have resolved this for one (stable for two weeks).

We're starting to roll this out to more services in the hope that it can be rolled out everywhere, so might be worth trying this out?

Comment: Thanks - will defo give this a try.

Comment: Just another update - this hasn't resolved it for one of our high traffic services, so feel it's an underlying dependency that could be causing the issue. We're going to try looking at some sort of diff checker on the dependencies to work out what's going on. Any update you can provide on whether it works for you would be brilliant

Comment: Hey - it looks like spring framework 5.2.6 does indeed fix the issue. We've now rolled it out to services that experienced the issue and they look healthier. The issue wasn't helped due to an internal library pulling in 5.2.4, so it had both versions on the classpath. Upgrading this and ensuring 5.2.6 is the spring version present seems to be the way to go